# Update android widget

Tags: android, android-widget

The [developer's site](http://developer.android.com/index.html) says that `onUpdate` method is invoked after time updatePeriodMillis. But when I write in the method `onUpdate`, for example, `Log.e ("tag", "update");`, he writes in the log only when you run a widget.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onUpdate()` is more like a "resume this widget now" handler. It should (re)initialize/start the widget's resources and services. The system will absolutely NOT respect very low `android:updatePeriodMillis` values, so using `onUpdate()` as mainloop for your widget will not work!

What you want to do is:

1. In `onUpdate()`: create a new `AlarmManager` with a `PendingIntent` with a custom action. Set the `AlarmManager` to repeat as fast as you need.
2. In `onReceive()`: pick up the custom action, and call `Log.e()` or whatever you want.

**Note:** After creating the custom action, don't forget to add it to your `<Intent-Filter>` in your Manifest.xml. Because otherwise, `onReceive()` will not be able to receive it.

Somewhat dated but still partly relevant: http://kmansoft.com/2010/04/10/processing-widget-events-with-pendingintents/